# What are the algebraic multiplicities of the eigenvalues of a Kronecker (or tensor) product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, kronecker-product

> What are the algebraic multiplicities of the eigenvalues of a tensor (i.e. Kronecker) product of linear transformations? We can assume that we are working in finite-dimensional vector spaces over an algebraically closed field.
> $\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$

Let's denote algebraic multiplicity by $\mu()$. It's easy to see from the matrix definition of trace (i.e., the trace is the sum of the diagonal) that
$$
\tr(A\otimes B) = \tr A \tr B.
$$
Since we also have $\tr(A) = \sum_\lambda \mu_A(\lambda)\lambda$, this strongly suggests to me that
$$
\mu_{A\otimes B}(\lambda) = \sum_{\lambda_A\lambda_B=\lambda}\mu_A(\lambda_A)\mu_B(\lambda_B).
$$
I don't really know to approach this claim, since I can't see a clear way to analyse $\det(A\otimes B - \lambda)$.  According to e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/a/188819, it should be true, but I don't know why. It's of course immediately clear that all the products $\lambda_A\lambda_B$ are eigenvalues of $A\otimes B$, but a priori, it's not even clear (to me) that there can't be other eigenvalues.

Update: Since originally posting, an answer has become clear in the comments, thanks to user8675309. I'll go ahead and post an answer based on the comments myself, but other perspectives (especially more abstract ones!) are of course welcome. Other approaches that only get the distinct eigenvalues without multiplicities are also welcome.

---

**Edit note:** This question originally also asked for the geometric multiplicities. I've moving that part to another post: [What are the geometric multiplicities of the eigenvalues of a Kronecker (or tensor) product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4685029/620957)

Comment: for some (upper) triangulations write $A= PRP^{-1}$ and $B=STS^{-1}\implies A\otimes B =  PRP^{-1} \otimes STS^{-1}$ $=\big(P\otimes S\big)\big(R\otimes S\big)\big(P^{-1}\otimes S^{-1}\big)=\big(P\otimes S\big)\big(R\otimes S\big)\big(P\otimes S\big)^{-1}$.  This gives you algebraic multiplicities and tells you that $A$ and $B$ diagonalizable implies their Kronecker product is diagonalizable.    I don't know further details about geometric multiplicities.

Comment: @user8675309 Aha! So to make sure I get it, we have that $A\otimes B$ is similar to $R\otimes T$, which itself is triangular. Looking at $R\otimes T$, we can directly read off the (algebraic) eigenvalues giving the desired results. Correct?

Comment: You've got it.  As an aside, since I like the trace I will point out that $(A\otimes B)^k =(A^k\otimes B^K)\implies \text{trace}\Big((A\otimes B)^k\Big)= \text{trace}\Big(A^k\Big)\cdot \text{trace}\Big(B^k\Big)$ which via Newton's Identities also gives the result about algebraic multiplicities when $\text{char }\mathbb F=0$.

Comment: @user8675309 Hm, so your trace identity implies $\sum \lambda^k = \sum(\lambda_A\lambda_B)^k$ (summed with multiplicity) for all $k$. And basically, this can only happen if we have $\lambda = \lambda_A\lambda_B$ pairwise, by some polynomial-flavoured argument (which is where I guess Newton's identities fit in?).

Comment: You can choose the basis for the $A$ and $B$ matrices separately, therefore you can consider both to be in Jordan Normal Form.  From there all that remains is to consider the behavior of the tensor product of two Jordan blocks. The Jordan blocks of eigenvalue $0$ seem to behave differently from the rest.  To get an intuition for the tensor product of two blocks use:
$(A\otimes B) (v_A \otimes v_b) = (A\; v_A)  \otimes ( B \;v_b)$.

The tensor product of two "linear forms acting on vectors" can be considered a linear form acting on the "matrix which is the tensor product of said vectors"

Comment: Should I actually split the question up after all, before we get full answers here? I'm realising that the answers will probably be mostly unrelated, so I'm not sure how best to handle this now. I would propose to keep and edit this post for the algebraic multiplicity (and perhaps add an answer myself), and make a separate post for the geometric. Should I do that? (Actually, I'll ask about this on meta)

Comment: @user3257842 Also, by your your comment I now have a revised conjecture for the geometric multiplicity (after running some Jordan matrices through Maple), which I'll include in the new post if I make it. It seems pretty solid - and indeed, the eigenvalue $0$ looks quite different.

Comment: There are $3$ cases to consider: when neither Jordan Block eigenvalues are $0$, when only one is $0$, and when both are $0$. Denote $J_{\lambda_1,n}$ to be a Jordan block of dimension  $n$ (of matrix $n*n$) and eigenvalue $\lambda_{1}$

Comment: When neither are $0$, the tensor product of the two Jordan Blocks has the structure of a single Jordan Block.  Ie. $J_{\lambda_1,n} \otimes J_{\lambda_2,m} \approx J_{\lambda_1\lambda_2,\;n*m}$ .  When only one is $0$, the tensor product has structure: $J_{0,n} \otimes J_{\lambda_2,m} \approx m\;J_{0,n}$ . So it splits into $m$ Jordan Blocks of dimension $n$.

Comment: @user3257842 I think your formula for the non-zero case is false. From experimenting, I seem to get, for $m\le n$ and $\lambda=\lambda_1\lambda_2$, $J_{\lambda_1,n}\otimes J_{\lambda_2,m} \approx J_{\lambda,n+m-1}\oplus J_{\lambda,n+m-3} \oplus \cdots \oplus J_{\lambda,n-m+1}$. The size of the blocks in the direct sum goes down by two each term.

Comment: @Milten Indeed, your formula seems to be correct. I should have checked for more examples.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I think I have it all now (well, not the full Jordan breakdown yet, but enough to get me the multiplicities). In particular, I've realized that we actually can't even deduce the geometric multiplicities in the tensor product only from the multiplicities in the factors. Take e.g. $(J_{2,2}\oplus J_{2,2})\otimes J_{3,2}$ and compare with $(J_{2,1}\oplus J_{2,3})\otimes J_{3,2}$. In the former, $\gamma(6)=2+2=4$, while in the latter, $\gamma(6)=1+2=3$. If and when I have the energy, I can write an answer myself (though some parts will be less abstract than I'd like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to user8675309.

Since we're working over an algebraically closed field, we can choose bases for $A$ and $B$ such that their matrices are (upper) triangular. They will have the eigenvalues (with multiplicity) $\{\lambda_{A,1}, \ldots, \lambda_{A,m}\}$ and $\{\lambda_{B,1}, \ldots, \lambda_{B,n}\}$ on the diagonals. The Kronecker product will then also be triangular, with entries
$$\left\{\lambda_{A,i}\lambda_{B,j}\mid 1\le i \le m, 1\le j\le n\right\}$$
on the diagonal. (This follows directly from the matrix formula of the Kronecker product). And we are done!

---

I also wanted to highlight the other nice approach of user8675309. Let $\sigma()$ denote the multiset of eigenvalues with multiplicity. We have, for any non-negative integer $k\ge 0$,
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr} \begin{split}
\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma(A\otimes B)} \lambda^k
&= \tr((A\otimes B)^k)\\
&= \tr(A^k\otimes B^k)\\
&= \tr(A^k)\tr(B^k)\\
&= \sum_{\lambda_A\in\sigma(A)} \lambda_A^k \sum_{\lambda_B\in\sigma(B)} \lambda_B^k\\
&= \sum_{\lambda_A,\lambda_B} (\lambda_A\lambda_B)^k.
\end{split}$$
Assuming now that the field has characteristic $0$, then letting $k$ vary shows that the terms on the left- and right-hand sides are equal. (I'm being a biiiit hand-wavy here, but I'm sure the formal argument can't be too bad. :p )